# Frame element strain-displacement relashionship

Tags: stress-strain

I want to find the matrix B in $$ε(x) = B(x) * u$$ where u is nodes displacements. $$B(x) = d^2/dx^2[N(x)]$$ where [N(x)] is a matrix of shape functions. The stiffnes matrix can be defined as $$K = \int_{0}^{L} [B^T][D][B] \,dx$$
with some coefficient.
The shape functions coefficients are not constant though. I thought that maybe I could integrate B like  $$ε = \int_{0}^{L}[B(x)]dx * u$$ But that would mean that the integral of multiplication equals to multiplication of integrals which is not true.
$$K = \int_{0}^{L} [B^T]\,dx * [D] * \int_{0}^{L}[B] \,dx$$
So how can I find the strain not in a particular point but an overall strain? Is there even such a thing for a frame element? Seeing that the stiffness matrix is constant for the hole element there can be. Thank you.